What does the phone do in the meantime between pressing the power button and the moment the screen lights on?
On almost every phone, when the phone is off (completely shut down) and you press and hold the power button to switch it on, why is there a delay between pressing the power button and lighting the screen on?
What is it even doing on a software level and why is it necessary?
